# How to integrated JIRA and Asterisk?

Tags: jira, asterisk

How to create issue in JIRA when a call generated in Asterisk?
In other word I want to create an issue in JIRA when I called a number and operator answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use AMI interface for listen for incoming call event or create hook in macro on answer

2) Use JIRA API to put tickets on jira and open popup.

or

1a) install FOP2 and use it for trigger script and popup.

Anyway you need read docs 1-2hr or more